# Adding items to list but when printing it's empty [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

Basically I'm using mongo to retrieve a list of documents, this is my code

```
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
mongoCollection.find().forEach(document -> {
    System.out.println(document);
    documentList.add(document);
}, ($, throwable) -> {});
System.out.println("Documents list -> " + documentList);
```

Console output:

```
[03:56:45 INFO]: Documents list -> []
[03:56:45 INFO]: Document{{_id=5f04090bda5751031475e022, GROUP=default, prefix=&f, weight=0}}
[03:56:45 INFO]: Document{{_id=5f04090bda5751031475e023, UUID=d369ab7f-fde6-378e-a059-038bd0bdc6d0, group=default}}
[03:56:45 INFO]: Document{{_id=5f049571da57511c9cc833be, UUID=2bb04fa1-1b39-3e43-ad7b-07f46d548b5a, group=default}}
```

As you can see it prints the list before even getting into the forEach, This is probably the weirdest issue I've faced in java, if anyone knows a fix please let me know.

Comment: Does maybe `mongoCollection.find()` return a `future` ?

Comment: It returns a FindIterable<Document>

Comment: is something in your code returns/starts a thread or a future?

Comment: The mongodb is async so it's without a doubt starting a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongo async driver was making a new thread which leads to the method just returning a list before the code is even executed, using a Completable Future solves the issue